# How to find relative lowering of vapour pressure from phase diagrams in terms of temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, vapor-pressure, colligative-properties

#### Problem

> [image: phase diagram]

#### Answer

> **C**

#### My question

Does a tie rule exist for solution solvent phase diagram to express relative lowering of vapour pressure in terms of temperature?

The phase diagram is the one provided as an explanation to colligative properties of binary solutions with one component non volatile.

Edit: Is there any relation between relative lowering of vapour pressure; relative elevation of boiling point and relative depression of freezing point ??

I think I found (  ∆p/p  = 1.23 ∆Tb/Tb) by differentiation of Clausis- Clayperon eqn and Troutons law; but am unsure.
If this is true? Can we approximate 1.23 as 1 ??( 1.23 was ∆Svap/R and ∆Svap  was put as 10.3)

Also does there exist a like rel for freezing point?

Comment: Please don't use Dropbox or any third-party cloud storage for uploading essential parts of the question. Instead, input the information as text or an image *directly*. Check your spelling and grammar. Also, please add your thoughts/argumentation.

Comment: There is some problem with my internet. So Dropbox is the only option. I tried to add directly five times but failed. I am new to stack exchange and therefore I am unaware of its many features.

Comment: I corrected the formatting and uploaded the illustration for you. I suspect you are using a mobile StackExchange app; if so, please switch to the web browser — the app is known for uploading issues, problems with rendering math and hasn't been updated in years.